# I am at the stage of adding Texture Paint and am getting missing UV's

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

I am trying to add texture paint but it does not show up when I go to the tab. When I do try use the paintbrush, I then get. waring sign about missing UV's. how do I fix this?

Comment: have you unwrapped your object, and also gave it an Image Texture?

Comment: I gave it an image texture in the Shading tab, I am following the Blender Guru's tutorial right now but I am held back by this bug

Comment: You are in *Solid* mode which is usually grey shading. If you want to see the material's colors select *Rendered* or *Material Preview* (key Z) -- As moonboots wrote, check the UVs in the *UV Editor* workspace. "Missing UVs" sounds like you have none.

Comment: So I added a UV map but when I go to the texture paint and brush it, it just paints over it and won't do spots. Brush settings are on mix

Comment: There is dozen of tutorials just pick one to learn basics if Andrew failed for you ... https://youtu.be/AnRQhH3fEDY